# count_ down _timer _upgrade

Tags: timer, countdown

I wrote a python code for a count down timer and it worked perfectly. Now I wanted to upgrade it. This is how my code works:
it takes hours, minutes and seconds from the user and turns all of them to seconds. After that, it will count down from that number to reach zero.
Now I want it instead of making a number based on the second, show the time like this > h:m:s and count down the seconds and when the seconds reach zero, it takes 1 from the minutes and resets the second to 60.

Here is my code:

```py
import os
import time

while True:
    wanna_continiue = input("do you want to start the timer? (y/n):> ")
    if "y" in wanna_continiue.lower():
        hour = int(input("enter hour(s):> "))
        minute = int(input("enter minute(s):> "))
        second = int(input("enter second(s):> "))
        sec_ = 60
        min_ = 60
        total = hour * 3600 + minute * 60 + second
        print("timer is starting now .....")
        time.sleep(1)
        while total >= 1:
            print( hour, ":", minute, ":", second)
            second -= 1
            if second == 0:
                minute -= 1
            time.sleep(1)
            os.system("cls")
        print("TIMER STOP")
    elif "n" in wanna_continiue.lower():
        print("have a good day :) ")
        break
    else:
        print("PLEASE ENTER y FOR yes AND n FOR no ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code to incorporate timedelta, you don't need to make that computation by hand.

```py
import os
import time
from datetime import timedelta

while True:
    wanna_continiue = input("do you want to start the timer? (y/n):> ")
    if "y" in wanna_continiue.lower():
        hour = int(input("enter hour(s):> "))
        minute = int(input("enter minute(s):> "))
        second = int(input("enter second(s):> "))
        total = hour * 3600 + minute * 60 + second
        print("timer is starting now .....")
        time.sleep(1)
        delta = timedelta(seconds = total)
        total-=1
        while total >= 1:
            print(f"{delta}")
            time.sleep(1)
            os.system("cls")
            delta=timedelta(seconds = total)
            total-=1
        print("TIMER STOP")
    elif "n" in wanna_continiue.lower():
        print("have a good day :) ")
        break
    else:
        print("PLEASE ENTER y FOR yes AND n FOR no ")
```